# Will increasing net.core.somaxconn make a difference?

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

I got into an argument on the net.core.somaxconn parameter: I was told that it will not make any difference if we change the default 128.

I believed this might be enough proof:

> "If the backlog argument is greater than the value in /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn, then it is silently truncated to that value" http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen

but it's not.

Does anyone know a method to testify this with two machines, sitting on a Gbit network?
The best would be against MySQL, LVS, apache2 ( 2.2 ), memcached.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Setting `net.core.somaxconn` to higher values is only needed on highloaded servers where new connection rate is so high/bursty that having 128 (50% more in BSD's: 128 `backlog` + 64 `half-open`) not-yet-accepted connections is considered normal. Or when you need to delegate definition of "normal" to an applications itself.

Some administrators use high `net.core.somaxconn` to hide problems with their services, so from user's point of view process it'll look like a latency spike instead of connection interrupted/timeout (controlled by `net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow` in Linux).

`listen(2)` manual says - `net.core.somaxconn` acts only upper boundary for an application which is free to choose something smaller (usually set in app's config). Though some apps just use `listen(fd, -1)` which means set backlog to the max value allowed by system.

Real cause is either low processing rate (e.g. a single threaded blocking server) or insufficient number of worker threads/processes (e.g. multi- process/threaded blocking software like `apache`/`tomcat`)

PS. Sometimes it's preferable to fail fast and let the load-balancer to do it's job(retry) than to make user wait - for that purpose we set `net.core.somaxconn` any value, and limit application backlog to e.g. `10` and set `net.ipv4.tcp_abort_on_overflow` to 1.

PPS. Old versions of Linux kernel have nasty bug of truncating `somaxcon` value to it's 16 lower bits (i.e. casting value to `uint16_t`), so raising that value to more than `65535` can even be dangerous. For more information see: http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/255460/

If you want to go into more details about all backlog internals in Linux, feel free to read:
[How TCP backlog works in Linux](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html).

Comment: Also worth noting: [since Linux 5.4 it was increased to 4096](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=19f92a030ca6d772ab44b22ee6a01378a8cb32d4).

Comment: ... and I thought that 16384 was way too much, but my home Synology NAS (ARMv8-based) sets it to... 65535!!!